# Shapefile into geojson conversion python 3

Tags: python, json, append, shapefile, gdal

```
output_buffer = []
for features in range(0,layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    result = feat.ExportToJson()
    output_buffer.append(result)
```

When I convert into geojson, I get output, but only one feature is getting formatted as JSON

I got  output like this:

```
{"geometry": {"coordinates": [488081.726322771, 2360837.62927308], "type": "Point"}, "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": {"EntityHand": null, "Layer": "pipe", "Linetype": null, "Text": "BB_D2", "ExtendedEn": null, "SubClasses": null}}{"geometry": {"coordinates": [487523.119248441, 2361228.95273474], "type": "Point"}, "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": {"EntityHand": null, "Layer": "pipe", "Linetype": null, "Text": "Mil_D2", "ExtendedEn": null, "SubClasses": null}}..................
```

I would like to get output like this:

```
{"geometry": {"coordinates": [488081.726322771, 2360837.62927308], "type": "Point"}, "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": {"EntityHand": null, "Layer": "pipe", "Linetype": null, "Text": "BB_D2", "ExtendedEn": null, "SubClasses": null}}**,**    
{"geometry": {"coordinates": [487523.119248441, 2361228.95273474], "type": "Point"}, "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": {"EntityHand": null, "Layer": "pipe", "Linetype": null, "Text": "Mil_D2", "ExtendedEn": null, "SubClasses": null}}**,**
```

Comment: Please format your question into something legible...

Comment: It would help if you provide a working example. Its impossible to answer if your problem cannot be replicated.

Comment: @RutgerKassies. The correct procedure is to make the appropriate close vote in that case.

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: Hey there Srinuvas Bathula: This answer is getting a lot of views, it's been nearly 3 years. As this is the sole answer and the question and answer are getting quite some positive feedback, would you mind marking it as correct ? :)

Comment: yes this almost  correct!!.helped to me sort out my problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For conversion between shapefile and geojson I would definitely use geopandas:

```
    import geopandas
    myshpfile = geopandas.read_file('myshpfile.shp')
    myshpfile.to_file('myJson.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

Answer (score 36):

Please check out the following library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.1.7

```
import shapefile
from json import dumps

# read the shapefile
reader = shapefile.Reader("my.shp")
fields = reader.fields[1:]
field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]
buffer = []
for sr in reader.shapeRecords():
    atr = dict(zip(field_names, sr.record))
    geom = sr.shape.__geo_interface__
    buffer.append(dict(type="Feature", \
    geometry=geom, properties=atr)) 
   
    # write the GeoJSON file
   
geojson = open("pyshp-demo.json", "w")
geojson.write(dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": buffer}, indent=2) + "\n")
geojson.close()
```

As noted in other answers, you could use geopandas:

```
import geopandas

shp_file = geopandas.read_file('myshpfile.shp')
shp_file.to_file('myshpfile.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

Answer (score 6):

To add onto @alexisdevarennes.

You can now convert to geojson using [PyShp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) in 1 or two lines:

```
import shapefile

with shapefile.Reader("shapefile.shp") as shp:
    geojson_data = shp.__geo_interface__
```

or

```
geojson_data = shapefile.Reader("shapefile.shp").__geo_interface__
```

example usage:

```
>>> geojson_data["type"]

'MultiPolygon'
```

Comment: This worked great but did not work with the .shp file for what I was doing; instead required the .dbf file.  I was using files provided from Census: https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.2018.html#list-tab-1556094155